# Bootstrap Carousel items not adding more than three items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 5 carousel and added 9 items

The first item is YouTube video and the other 7 items is empty Divs with background-image

the problem is the first three items is the only working items and I just see three indicators

And when I try to display the fourth item, the carousel stops working

```
<section class="slider">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel h-100" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0"
                class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
            <div class="carousel-item h-100 active">
                <iframe class="w-100 h-100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z6nvbmqYR9g"
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-one h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-three h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-four h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-five h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-six h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-seven h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-eight h-100">

            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about it, you only have 3 buttons, so that must be something with that, try adding more buttons.

```html
<section class="slider">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel h-100" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0"
                class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="4"
                aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="5"
                aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="6"
                aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
        </div>
        // And more buttons
        <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
            <div class="carousel-item h-100 active">
                <iframe class="w-100 h-100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z6nvbmqYR9g"
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-one h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-three h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-four h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-five h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-six h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-seven h-100">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-eight h-100">

            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only three carousel indicator. You can take off carousel indicator or add 4 more divs .

Here is a working fiddle that i modified your code.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section class="slider">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel h-100" data-bs-ride="carousel">
       
        <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
            <div class="carousel-item h-100 active">
                <iframe class="w-100 h-100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z6nvbmqYR9g"
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-one h-100"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two h-100"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-three h-100"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-four h-100"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-five h-100"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/550">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-six h-100"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-seven h-100"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/750">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-eight h-100"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/850">

            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</section>
```